# How to filter Image by date in Earth Engine?

Tags: google-earth-engine

I have found some sets of data, for example GEDI L4B which it says that has images for 2 years between 2019 and 2021. Since this is not an Image Collection, how do I get the values for some specific days?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GEDI L4B image is a composite image that includes observations from 2019 to 2021; however, the date of the observations cannot be consulted in that product. Nevertheless, there is another lower-level GEDI image collection available in GEE (GEDI L2A: `ee.ImageCollection("LARSE/GEDI/GEDI02_A_002_MONTHLY")`) which contains the acquisition date of the data. You might want to take a look at that collection.

Comment: Thankyou very much!